# Spring @autowired is not loading the bean - throws NULL pointer

Tags: spring, web

I have a very simple project setup. 
Spring 4.14
Jersey 2.15

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.talentera</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

For some reason, @Autowired not working or the beans are not being scanned.
Below is my project setup:
[image]

Below is the spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.talentera">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Below is the usage:

```
 @Component
    @Path("/user")
    @Scope("request")
    public class UserRestService extends BaseAPIService{

        @Autowired
        UserManagementService userManagementService;
        protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog( UserRestService.class.getName() );

        EmailFormatValidator emailValidator = new EmailFormatValidator();



        public UserManagementService getUserManagementService() {
            return userManagementService;
        }

        public void setUserManagementService(UserManagementService userManagementService) {
            this.userManagementService = userManagementService;
        }

     @GET
        @Path("/get/{userId}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getUser(@PathParam("userId") Integer userId)
        {
            System.out.println(getSerRequest().getSession().getId());
            User u = userManagementService.getUserById(userId);
            response.setData(u);
            return jsonStringifyResponse();
        }

package com.talentera.common.service.impl;


imports,,,,

    @Service("userManagementService")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public class UserManagementServiceImpl extends AbstractService<Identifiable> implements UserManagementService
    {
```

This throws a NULL pointer exception since userManagementService is NULL.

Please help me with your findings. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how are you loading your spring context? web.xml?  Why use xml at all?  Why not just use the JavaConfig?

Comment: @dres, Thanks for the reply, well I used to do with the XML earlier and followed the same, and yet I am loading my spring context through web.xml, It is recognozing @ Components fine, but not the @ Service probably.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're including the Jersey-Spring integration module. Your service is a Jersey bean, and just adding Spring annotations doesn't make it a Spring bean.

Comment: @chrylis. You are right. Thank you. I added it. Then faced another problem: I realized that the Jersey version that I used had dependency on spring 3 and as a result, it was including Spring 3 Jars(Maven dependency). Also I had Spring 4 Jars included. So there was a Jar conflict. I ended up excluding spring3 jars from jersey-spring3 dependency. that worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like adding this to your xml might solve the problem. If you are picking from a specific list of annotations you would also need to add the autowired annotation in their.

```
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Autowired" />
```